# Using default people picker on custom form

Tags: 2013, custom-form, people-picker

I have found some posts that have a little information on the topic but nothing that has an answer.

Is there a way to get the OOTB people picker to work on a custom form?  The best that I have gotten right now is to render the correct control by replacing:

`<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff3{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" />` - (Deleted some out to keep it clean)

with

`<SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker runat="server" id="ff3{$Pos}" />`

Doing this will let me select a user but when I save the form the field is blank.  Is there any other way around this to get this control to work?

Related:

- [Client people picker in custom form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23061948/clientpeoplepicker-in-customform)
- [peoplepicker on custom forms via SPD in SP2013](http://sharepoint-community.net/forum/topics/peoplepicker-on-custom-forms-via-sp-designer-in-sp-2013)

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84324/getting-value-from-peoplepicker-peopleeditor

Answer (score 0):

Consider the JQuery web services library: http://spservices.codeplex.com/ for custom forms.  This thing works on 2007, 2010 and 2013.  It requires JQuery UI's CSS files though.

Comment: I don't believe that will work for my situation, SPServices has SPFindPeoplePicker. I have an existing field that works in my form, I just want it to be like the OOTB people picker on the default forms.  I don't want to have to click and check for names and have to open the address book.

Comment: Okay, but was referring more to autocomplete: http://sympmarc.com/2011/08/24/using-spservices-with-jqueryuis-autocomplete-function-on-infopath-forms-in-sharepoint/.  This worked fine in a OOTB form by inserting the JQuery in the ASPX with a content editor WP.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what type of custom form (xlst, csr, or something other) you develop and what type of field used.
If a field type is user/group then sharepoint should generate default People Picker Control in you custom from by
`<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff3{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" />`

If you use text field and want use picker then try OOTB JS Client Side People Picker https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593.aspx. It is situable for all sharepoint forms